# Displaying Lots of Bitmap on ImageView in few seconds

Tags: android, android-imageview, loading, bitmapimage

I want to display around 150 frames in 5 sec ( 30fps) on Android imageview .All frames are stored in SdCard from there i loaded into Bitmap Arraylist .
For ex
iToD Arraylist of Bitmap
mBitmap (Bitmap Object)

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    mBitmap = iToD.get( i );    
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
}
```

But its not able to render all frames i want it should able to render all frames .Giving me some kind of sliding effect.

Comment: In a `for loop`, the limit is 99 bitmaps.

Comment: It will not work. You need to create a video file and play the video using `VideoView`

Comment: use frame animation to meet your requirements.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib yes i know but how to display all 99 image

Comment: @Budius I dont want to create a video file from the frames

Comment: @XtreemDeveloper I tried but not working as expected if you have any idea please suggest me. Thank you

Comment: I can see you don't want to create it, but it doesn't matter what you want. What it matters is what is possible to do. ImageView was not built with 30fps in mind and you won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a handler.

```
final int index = 0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(iToD.get( index++ ));
        if(index != iToD.size()) {
        handler.post(this);

    }

};
handler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                Hi,

                Try this

                    AnimationDrawable animDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();


               // Create as many drawable as needed and add it to the AnimationDrawable.

                for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    mBitmap = iToD.get( i );    
                   Drawable frame = new BitmapDrawable(b1);
                    animDrawable.addFrame(frame, 250);
                }

        //Then create an ImageView and set the background as the animationDrawable.
        mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable);

    Handler startAnimation = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        animDrawable.start();
      }
    };


    //and call the handler as

    Message msg = new Message();
    startAnimation.sendMessage(msg);

For More information refer this link,
http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/02/animation-through-bitmap.html
```